# Erro in model.fit().! How to Solve it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Im working  on  a skin cancer Detection and  classification  i wrote this code, but i have faced some problem on how compiling and fitting this model ? And thank you.

can't run model.fit() . it generate  error : Graph execution error.

Could  you Help me  fix this  and  thank you .

```
    # Importing Modules  needed
    from tensorflow import keras
    # Forming datasets
    datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, validation_split=0.3)
    # Training and validation dataset
    train1 = datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/hamza/Desktop/kkk/TrainD', target_size=(224,224), subset='training')
    val = datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/hamza/Desktop/kkk/TrainD', target_size=(224,224), subset='validation')
    
    # Test dataset for evaluation
    datagen2 = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
    
    test = datagen2.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/hamza/Desktop/kkk/TestD')
    
    from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dropout,BatchNormalization
    input_shape=(224,224,3)
    droprate = 0.2
    
    
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Conv2D(512,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape,padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(droprate))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    
    
    model.add(Conv2D(256,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Dropout(droprate))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Dropout(droprate))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(droprate))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer='SGD',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
epochs = 10
batch_size = 32
callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(
        monitor='val_acc', 
        patience=2,
        mode='max',
        verbose=1)
]

vgg_history = model.fit(train1,batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,verbose=1,validation_data=val,shuffle=True,callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback. We can not guess the rest of the error.

Comment: model.complie() runs without error ?

Comment: Yes model.compile() works without error

Comment: https://prnt.sc/4dNDW01nvCIg here is  the  trace @Frightera

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using generators you should not specify the batch size in model.fit